# Pass an instance of the subclass to a method and use it later within that method

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I have a method (prepareErrorMessage) that accepts objects of type ErrorMessagePojoSuperclass. However, I only pass subclasses of ErrorMessagePojoSuperclass as arguments:

```
public class ErrorMessagePojoBundle extends ErrorMessagePojoSuperclass {}

public class Tester {
    ErrorMessagePojoBundle empb = new ErrorMessagePojoBundle();
    prepareErrorMessage(empb);

    public void prepareErrorMessage(ErrorMessagePojoSuperclass errorMessagePojo) {   
        String errorStatusMsg = messageConverter.convertXMLToString(errorMessagePojo);                             
    }
}
```

The class ErrorMessagePojoBundle has more methods than its superclass.

I need to make sure that when the line of code is running `messageConverter.convertXMLToString(errorMessagePojo)`, messageConverter processes an instance of the subclass - in this case the object empb. Any ideas? I want to solve this without the use of casting. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The method *will* be processing an instance of the subclass, but it won't be able to call any new methods on it without casting, because the compiler won't know that those methods exist. It would be easier to help if you could provide a [mcve] though - currently the code is incomplete and also wouldn't compile. (You have a non-declaration statement which isn't in a method/constructor.)

Comment: ^^ separately, when doing an MCVE, it's useful to pick simple, easy-to-differentiate names like `SuperClass` and `SubClass`. Long names only differentiated at the end get in the way a bit.

Comment: Hello @Duke,  Make `static ErrorMessagePojoBundle empb = new ErrorMessagePojoBundle();` else compiler will complain. After this the methods called wil be of `ErrorMessagePojoBundle empb`, not of its super class.

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas? I want to solve this without the use of casting.

Your options are:

1. Defining an interface with the necessary method, having the subclass implement it, and using that interface as the parameter type rather than the superclass.
2. Changing the parameter type to the subclass, not the superclass.
3. `instanceof` and casting (not usually what you want to do).

1 and 2 are basically just variants of each other.

In your example code, there's no reason for `prepareErrorMessage` to accept the superclass rather than the subclass (or an interface), since the *only* thing it does can only be done with the subclass (or something implementing the same interface).